# What do I use the coffee beans for?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In "Animal Crossing: New Leaf," the owner of Roost Cafe lets you work part-time and gives you some beans, according on how well you served the customers. The problem is, I don't know how to use them! Can someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The coffee beans are **completely useless** except for selling purposes. You do also get a coffee maker from Brewster, but it is purely for decoration.

All of the beans can be sold for up to four times more (minus one) via the flea market than to Reese - for example, the superb beans fetch 2000 with Reese and up to 7999 on the flea market.

Answer (score 1):

They are useless unless you sell them. I recommend you selling them on the flea market,you get more bells! I have tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Go to        http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/the-roost-cafe/    they give you a whole list of how to make coffee for all customers, including special ones like Isabelle and DJ KK. If you get all customer's orders right Brewster will give you Superb Coffee Beans, the best ones he stocks. They are of course, only given to you to be sold, and are basicly purposeless. Brewster will occasionally give you special furniture that looks like you could actually make your own coffee with the beans, but they are only for displaying.